# Areas to reduce WAR (based on Java EE) file size

Tags: websphere, war, ear

I have one EAR file which contains 3 different web application 'war' files.

Project Environment: MAVEN, Java/Java EE, Spring, JSF, Hibernate/JPA, Oracle, WebSphere

My Ear size has reached 81.6152 MB. Due to this my EAR deployment is slow.

Please provide some suggestions and areas where I can reduce my EAR file size and improve deployment time?

Answer (score 0):

You can create **shared libraries** for your application libraries (e.g. Spring) and link them to your enterprise application or to your web modules separately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a good idea. I am using this concept.